# Ubuntu 20.04 can't see newly installed SSD

Tags: 20.04, ssd, nvme, m2

I installed a Samsung 970 Evo M.2 NVMe drive. It isn't recognized by Ubuntu, but it's visible in the BIOS. My motherboard is an MSI B450 Tomahawk MAX.

[image]

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and updated SSD firmware? With Samsung I was able to download a ISO and boot that to update as I do not have Windows.https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/

Answer (score 0):

Switch your disk setting in the BIOS from RAID to AHCI

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Ubuntu can see it in the Disks application; it's just that it isn't partitioned or anything.

Comment: did you resolve this? this seems to be exactly my problem. i have the new drive in a usb enclosure. Disks (iirc) sees it, but is not really accessible. Neither gparted, not clonezilla see it at all. Not sure what to do next.